# Why My Code not Give jwtToken in Postman Result with register user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am buliding simple curd app using spring boot with jwt.when i register user using postman ContentType/json , when i submit all details i get response all details user details with 201 code but
token  = null i get.
here i added jwt filter and user controller file please check and help me where i miss the code.

Here is my code

## JwtTokenProvider

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    @Value("${app.jwt.secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${app.jwt.token.prefix}")
    private String jwtTokenPrefix;

    @Value("${app.jwt.header.string}")
    private String jwtHeaderString;

    @Value("${app.jwt.expiration-in-ms}")
    private Long jwtExpirationInMs;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String generateToken(Authentication auth){
        String authorities = auth.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
      
        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(auth.getName())
                .claim("roles", authorities)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + jwtExpirationInMs))
                //.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512, jwtSecret).compact();
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES512, jwtSecret.getBytes()).compact();
                
    }
    public Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request){
        String token = resolveToken(request);
        if(token == null){
            return null;
        }
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        String username = claims.getSubject();
        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.stream(claims.get("roles").toString().split(","))
                .map(role -> role.startsWith("ROLE_")?role:"ROLE_"+role)
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return username!= null ? new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities): null;
    }

    public boolean validateToken(HttpServletRequest request){
        String token = resolveToken(request);
        if(token == null){
            return false;
        }
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
        if(claims.getExpiration().before(new Date())){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req){
        //Bearer key...
        String bearerToken = req.getHeader(jwtHeaderString);
        if(bearerToken!=null && bearerToken.startsWith(jwtTokenPrefix)){
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

## authFilter

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                  JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        jwtTokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(request);

        if(authentication !=null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(request)){
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

## userController

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    private TransactionService transactionService;

    @PostMapping("/api/user/registration")
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody User user){
        if(userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername())!=null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        //default role.
        user.setRole(Role.USER);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.saveUser(user), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/user/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(Principal principal){
        //principal = httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal.
        if(principal == null){
            //logout will also use here so we should return ok http status.
            return ResponseEntity.ok(principal);
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal;
        User user = userService.findByUsername(authenticationToken.getName());
        user.setToken(tokenProvider.generateToken(authenticationToken));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Please help me..

Comment: What class is calling your `JwtTokenProvider`? Do you have a controller ? A filter ?

Comment: I added controller and jwtfilte file please check it now @RUARO Thibault2

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to be noted.

1. You are trying to see the JWT token in response body after calling user registration. But token generating method generateToken() is called in user login method getUser() and NOT in user registration method register(). So token will not be generated when you register. Try user login, token will be generated.
2. You are passing JWT token in response body. Ideally you should be passing it in the response header 'Authorization'. You can use  response.addHeader('Authorization', token).

Answer (score 0):

### First: Get an output

When you send a POST request to your Controller ("/api/user/registration"), you never call your `JwtTokenProvider` class. Therefor, the token is never generated.

Try the following:

```
@PostMapping("/api/user/registration")
    public ResponseEntity<String> register(@RequestBody User user){
        if(userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername())!=null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        //default role.
        user.setRole(Role.USER);
        userService.saveUser(user);
// I am not sure if this is really correct, but it should do it... Otherwise, change this method.
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken  auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getRoles());
        String token = tokenProvider.generateToken(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(token);
    }
```

You should have an output.

### Second: use the header

One you have a first output with the token, then you can try adding the token in the Header, or anywhere you want. Give it a try, a let me know.